# Put the data in the list with Elixir pipeine and Enum

Tags: enums, elixir, pipeline

Good afternoon. I have a module to get the domain name from the link.

```
defmodule URIparser do
  defstruct domains: []
  def make_domain(uri) do
    case URI.parse(uri) do
      %URI{authority: nil} -> URI.parse("http://#{uri}")
      %URI{authority: _} -> URI.parse(uri)
    end
  end
end
```

After that I use the pipeline and get the domain I need.

```
links = ["https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&sxsrf", "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask", "yahoo.com"]
Enum.each(links, fn(x) -> URIparser.make_domain(x) |> Map.take([:authority]) |> Map.values |> IO.inspect end)
```

That's what happens in the end:

```
["google.com"]
["stackoverflow.com"]
["yahoo.com"]
:ok
```

Please tell us how to complement the pipeline and to put all domains into one list. Other solutions are also available.

Example:

```
%{domains: ["google.com", "stackoverflow.com", "yahoo.com"]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Enum.each` and `Map.take`, use `Enum.map` and `Map.get`

```
Enum.map(links, fn x ->
  x
  |> URIparser.make_domain()
  |> Map.get(:authority)
end)
```

Comment: Thanks alot, Kabie